# Error when deploying Next.js website with MongoDB API

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, vercel

I've recently deployed my `Next.js` website to `tekmucreations.tech`, and I'm encountering an error related to my MongoDB API. The API works fine locally at `http://localhost:3000/api/posts`, but I'm struggling to adapt it to my deployed domain URL.

Here's the error message I'm receiving:

[image: error message on vercel]

Here are a couple more screenshots to add more context:

[image: route.js file]

and this I believe is the file were the error is emanating from:

[image: blog page]

I attempted to update the URL on line 6 from http://localhost:3000/api/posts to https://tekmucreations.tech/api/posts, but unfortunately, this change did not resolve the error:

[image: localhost:3000/api/posts]

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of this error is that the build process attempts to fetch the server itself which isn't running during build time at all.

Instead, you can use fetch on the client-side.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77278408/22803312